# Calculate Sum of All Elements in a Matrix GSL

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, gsl

I'm wondering what is the best way of calculating the sum of all elements in a matrix in GSL (Gnu scientific library). I don't see any library functions that do this, so will I just need to sum over all the indices myself?

Comment: It's O(m x n), no matter how you do it. That's as fast as you can go, unless you can use a thread per row and do a map/reduce solution.  That's it.

Comment: That solves the question. How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: I don't know.  Why not answer it yourself and vote it up?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest a solution can get is `O(m*n)`, so a simple summing iteration over the matrix is the best solution.

Comment: If you access the `data` pointer to the elements it can be faster than accessing with two indices. (Still O(m*n)).